# JavaFx program freezes when adding data to area chart

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, charts

I am trying to show data in an area chart in JavaFx. The problem is that the entire program freezes permanently when populating the area chart (this behaviour doesn't stop once the data is visible in the chart).

The code below shows the function which populates the area chart with data. The 'createChart' function runs in a background thread and uses "Platform.runLater" for all UI commands.

```
@FXML
private AreaChart<String, Number> mAreaChart;

public void createChart(String mainTitle, HashMap<Integer, String> chart_time, HashMap<Integer, Float> chart_data) {
    try {
        XYChart.Series<String, Number> series = new XYChart.Series<String, Number>();
        for (int k = 0; k < chart_time.size(); k++) {
            series.getData().add(new XYChart.Data<String, Number>(chart_time.get(k), chart_data.get(k)));
        }
        chart_time.clear();
        chart_data.clear();

        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAreaChart.setAnimated(false);
                mAreaChart.setTitle(mainTitle);
                mAreaChart.getXAxis().setLabel("Time");
                mAreaChart.getYAxis().setLabel("Movement");
                mAreaChart.getXAxis().setTickLabelRotation(45);
                mAreaChart.setCreateSymbols(false);
                mAreaChart.getData().clear();
                mAreaChart.getData().add(series);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The ".add(series);" command causes the problem. Since it is already happening in a background thread and there is only one JavaFX UI thread, I wonder how I can stop the program from freezing?

Comment: How much data are you adding to the chart?

Comment: Thousands of data points. Usually between 5000 to 7000 data points, which each consist of a string and a double value.

Comment: The JavaFX Chart API isn't really designed for that much data, unfortunately. It creates a UI node for each data point, so your layout code is just going to take a really long time with that kind of data volume. You probably need to look for a different solution if you have that much data; either find a way to graph only representative data, build your own chart implementation, or find a third-party library.